# Efficient Way to Prepare an Apache Commons Pool of Nashorn Engines

Tags: java, nashorn, apache-commons-pool

I am using [Apache Commons Pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/) to create a pool of Nashorn engines. On application start I call [`preparePool()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPool.html#preparePool--) to warm up the `minIdle` number of instances to `eval()` all scripts into the engine so that it is ready to answer calls to `invokeFunction()` immediately.

**The warmup**

```java
@Override
public NashornScriptEngine create() {
    // ...
    try {
        engine.eval(asset1);
        engine.eval(asset2);
        engine.eval(asset3);
    } // ...
    return engine;
}
```

Depending on the pool size and the complexity of the preloaded scripts this takes a considerable amount of time.

**Questions**

- Can I warmup only one instance and safely clone it to the number of `minIdle` instances?
- Could a clone of a created instance be safely serialized and persisted? (which would allow maintaining an engine cache that only needed to be invalidated if one of the assets changes)

**Related resources** (will update this section when appropriate)

- [SO: Clone Entire JavaScript Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116120/clone-entire-javascript-scriptengine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nashorn's engine instances aren't either cloneable or serializable. I would suggest that you use a single engine instance though and use `ScriptEngine.createBindings()` to create multiple `Bindings` objects and pool those. You'll obviously need to initialize each Bindings with a call to `ScriptEngine.eval(String|Reader, Bindings)` method then. (You can also use `ScriptContext` objects instead of just `Bindings`; they're practically tuples of bindings and out/err streams.)

The benefit of using a single `ScriptEngine` is code sharing. Evaluating the same script into multiple bindings will still only compile the script once (if you use the `Compilable` interface) and the code for all function objects will be represented by the same compiled bytecode.